# PostgreSQL query from server won't update table

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, express

I am sure I am missing something super simple here, but I can't get my database table to update properly when I run the following query from my server. I know I am connected to my database because I can remove the variables and add hardcoded data and I can make the proper updates.

My query looks like this:

```
router.post('/userQuestionnaire', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.user_id;
  const question = req.body.question;
  const response = req.body.response.toString().toUpperCase();
  console.log(question, response);

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  let sqlText = `UPDATE user_questionnaire SET (${question}) = (select id from response_enum where value=$1) WHERE user_id = $2;`;
  pool
    .query(sqlText,[response, id])
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      res.send(response.rows);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error posting questionnaire', err);
    });
});
```

Not sure if there is an obvious bug here or what I am missing.

Comment: Two possibilities: there is no row with that `user_id` or you forgot to commit the transaction.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, I know there is a row with that user_id.  How do I check if I commit the transaction.  I was able to successfully make the DB update by replacing all of the variables with actual values (taken from the console log).